# Passing a variable/column name as an argument/parameter to a function

Tags: r, nse

This is a beginner's question, but after researching and trying for a day, I seem to be unable to find the answer myself (and I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I have not found a solution). I would like to pass the name of a variable (column in a dataframe) to a function. I suppose that the passed string is not simply a string, but a (more complex) object, which might be why the following minimal code fails:

```
dfprod <- data.frame("demand" = c(59000, 51000, 40000, 29000, 20000))

my_fun <- function(x_var) {
  mean(dfprod$x_var)
}

my_fun(demand)
```

I have tried numerous solution, such as embracing {{ x_var }}, using eval, paste, substitute - all to no avail. Could you point me in the right direction? The string "demand", passed to the function, should be replaced for the string "x_var" in the function.

When I run the code from above, R (4.3.3 on Windows 11 with RStudio) gives me:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(dfprod$x_var) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The desired output is:

```
> my_fun(demand)
[1] 39800
```

Comment: E.g. this works `dfprod = data.frame(demand = c(59000, 51000, 40000, 29000, 20000)); my_fun = \(x_var) { mean(x_var) }; my_fun(dfprod$demand)`. However, I suspect you are looking for `my_fun = \(df, x_var) { mean(df[, x_var]) }; my_fun(dfprod, "demand")`

Comment: The complicated stuff starts here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html You might  read previous chapters first.

Comment: @Friede You almost certainly want to use `df[[x_var]]` instead of `df[, x_var]`. The latter can yield incorrect results for subclasses of `data.frame` (such as `tbl_df` from ‘tibble’), whereas the former will always be the correct way of extracting a single column from a data.frame.

Comment: Always pass all variables used in a function, such as the column and data frame here, as parameters to get clearer and more reliable code! It is best practice that helps to avoid errors and hassle due to non-existent objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use `$` with nonstandard evaluation in the way you’re attempting. Instead, you can use `eval()` and pass your dataframe as the evaluation environment:

```r
my_fun <- function(x_var) {
  mean(eval(substitute(x_var), envir = dfprod))
}

my_fun(demand)
# [1] 39800
```

Or similarly, using rlang:

```r
library(rlang)

my_fun <- function(x_var) {
  mean(eval_tidy(ensym(x_var), data = dfprod))
}

my_fun(demand)
# [1] 39800
```

Also, it’s generally better practice to explicitly pass the dataframe as a function argument (eg, `my_fun <- function(x_var, data)`) than to rely on an object in the global environment.

Comment: Using `eval()` here is complete overkill, error-prone and dangerous (also probably inefficient). You don’t need to — and should not! — evaluate simple names. Instead, resolve them in the respective context using whatever’s the appropriate function: `[[`, `getElement()`, `get()`…

Comment: `subset.data.frame()` doesn’t evaluate names, it evaluates arbitrary expressions (that expression could be a single names in the simplest case, but generally isn’t). It needs to use `eval()`.

Comment: I also now see that its documentation warns, “This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.”